# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - getting user id

Tags: asp.net

I see many similar questions, but not a single good answer. I'm using Forms Authentication and I would like to find AD account (domain/username) of the user that is currently logged in. I'm complete beginner in this field, and I would apriciate an example of how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I Used this to get my User Name of the user

```
            username = (Session["UserName"].ToString()).Split('\\');
            pUsername.InnerText = username[1];
```

try getting it from the session the one that is used for validation u can get that there 
or u can do one thing is that get it from the database through `SP` on `LoginClick` store it in session and get it back where u need it.
I got it like this.

```
                LP.UserName = UserName;
                DataSet dsUserName = LBLL.validate_user(LP);
                if (dsUserName.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Session["UserName"] = dsUserName.Tables[0].Rows[0]["userName"].ToString();
                    Session["entityUID"] = dsUserName.Tables[0].Rows[0]["entityUID"].ToString();
                    Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx", false);
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Invalid Credentials. Please contact administrator!";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Security; // this will give you access to membership.
```

Inside your event:

```
// 2 examples:
bool loggedIn = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
string un = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I'm using "Forms" together with anonymous authentication and this doesn't work! Thanks for trying to help.